# Read .txt file with C program and parse, how to handle empty fields

Tags: c

I try to parse some data of a .txt file, and the format is not really easy to handle. The separator is a space character. The file contains one field with variable length, this is the fifth column from the right side. Therefore, until the fourth column I parse the date from left, then I begin to parse the data from right, until I reach the field with the variable length. This works ok. But my main problem is that I have sometimes fields where is nothing in there, see third row column 3. Because of that with my code I cannot parse the data accurately. In the output file the parsing is not ok for all lines. Is there a possibility to skip empty fields so that sscanf can recognize this fields? It would be very nice if someone can give me a tip how I can parse the data correctly.
Code at onlinegdb: https://onlinegdb.com/8rOBlIfMhU

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF 1500

// reverse a string
char *strrev(char *str)
{
      char *p1, *p2;

      if (! str || ! *str)
            return str;
      for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
      {
            *p1 ^= *p2;
            *p2 ^= *p1;
            *p1 ^= *p2;
      }
      return str;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr=fopen("/tmp/abc123", "w");
    fputs(
   "10000   07/01/1986   68391610   68391610   OPTIMUM MANUFACTURING INC             OMFGA          7952    10                 10396      3       3         3990       3990     39       399    03/12/1986   OMFGA                     Q          A         R       -2.56250         1000         .             2.75000        2.37500        .             .             .       C             C           3680       2    30/01/1986      .          .            .         .              .                 .       .          .             .          .             .             .        1.00000     1.00             .            .            .        .        .      1        1        9       2       0.013809     0.013800     0.011061     0.011046     0.014954\n"
   "12781   30/11/1970   84857L10   50558810   LACLEDE GAS CO                        LG            21080    11                     0      1       1         4925       2741     27       274             .                             N          A         R       25.00000         3500         .            25.00000       24.00000        .             .             .      0.041667      0.041667     4141       .             .      .          .            .         .              .                 .       .          .             .          .             .             .        4.00000     4.0              .            .            .        .        .      .        .        .       .       0.016698     0.016439     0.021276     0.020949     0.014779\n"
   "13901   27/05/1955   02209S10              PHILIP MORRIS & CO LTD                              21398    11                     0      1       1         2110       2111     21       211             .                             N          A         R       42.00000         4400       40.87500       42.00000       40.87500        .             .             .      0.030675      0.030675      2887       .             .      .          .            .         .              .                 .       .          .             .          .             .             .        2479.29   576.000            .            .            .        .        .      .        .        .       .       0.001626     0.001543     0.001477     0.001381      .\n"    
   "13901   31/05/1955   02209S10              PHILIP MORRIS & CO LTD                              21398    11                     0      1       1         2110       2111     21       211             .                             N          A         R       41.37500         5600       42.12500       42.12500       41.00000        .             .             .     -0.014881     -0.014881      2887       .             .      .          .            .         .              .                 .       .          .             .          .             .             .        2479.29   576.000            .            .            .        .        .      .        .        .       .       0.000496     0.000165    -0.000448    -0.000851      .\n"    
   "13901   01/06/1955   02209S10              PHILIP MORRIS INC                                   21398    11                     0      1       1         2110       2111     21       211    01/07/1962                             N          A         R       40.00000        11300       40.87500       40.87500       40.00000        .             .             .     -0.033233     -0.033233      2887       2    29/12/1955      .          .            .         .              .                 .       .          .             .          .             .             .        2479.29   576.000            .            .            .        .        .      .        .        .       .       0.001683     0.001476    -0.000496    -0.000724      .\n"      
   "13901   02/06/1955   02209S10              PHILIP MORRIS INC                                   21398    11                     0      1       1         2110       2111     21       211             .                             N          A         R       39.87500         9600       40.00000       40.12500       39.87500        .             .             .     -0.003125     -0.003125      2887       .             .      .          .            .         .              .                 .       .          .             .          .             .             .        2479.29   576.000            .            .            .        .        .      .        .        .       .       0.003036     0.002973     0.002027     0.001912      .\n"      
   "13901   03/06/1955   02209S10              PHILIP MORRIS INC                                   21398    11                     0      1       1         2110       2111     21       211             .                             N          A         R       40.12500         5500       40.00000       40.62500       40.00000        .             .             .      0.006270      0.006270      2887       .             .      .          .            .         .              .                 .       .          .             .          .             .             .        2479.29   576.000            .            .            .        .        .      .        .        .       .       0.006440     0.006420     0.004233     0.004141      .\n"      
  ,ptr);
    fclose(ptr);

    FILE *fp, *fpp;
    fp=fopen("/tmp/abc123","r");
        char puffer[BUF];
        char a[1000],b[1000],c[1000],d[1000],e[1000],f[1000],g[1000],h[1000],i[1000],j[1000],k[1000],l[1000],m[1000],n[1000],o[1000],p[1000],q[1000],r[1000],s[1000],tt[1000],u[1000],v[1000]; // a->PERMNO; b->date; c->CUSIP; d->NCUSIP; e->COMNAM; f->DIVAMT; g->CFACPR
        char w[1000],x[1000],y[1000],z[1000],aa[1000],ab[1000],ac[1000],ad[1000],ae[1000],af[1000],ag[1000],ah[1000],ai[1000],aj[1000],ak[1000],al[1000],am[1000],an[1000],ao[1000],ap[1000];
        char aq[1000],ar[1000],as[1000],at[1000],au[1000],av[1000],aw[1000],ax[1000],ay[1000],az[1000],ba[1000],bb[1000],bc[1000],bd[1000],be[1000],bf[1000],bg[1000],bh[1000],bi[1000],bj[1000],bk[1000],bl[1000] ;
      
    fpp=fopen("output.txt","w");

    if(fpp==NULL)
    {
        printf("file could not be opened\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
  while(fgets(puffer, BUF, fp) != NULL)
    {
        int n1,n2;
        char t[1000];
        //parse first four columns from left side
        if( 4==sscanf(puffer,"%s%s%s%s%n",a,b,c,d,&n1) )
        //parse 57 cloumns from the right side
        if( 57 ==sscanf(strrev(strcpy(t,puffer)),"%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%n",bl,bk,bj,bi,bh,bg,bf,be,bd,bc,bb,ba,az,ay,ax,aw,av,au,at,as,ar,aq,ap,ao,an,am,al,ak,aj,ai,ah,ag,af,ae,ad,ac,ab,aa,z,y,x,w,v,u,tt,s,r,q,p,o,n,m,l,k,j,i,h,g,f,&n2));
        //parse the variable field, is simply what is left in the middle.
        if( 1==sscanf(puffer+n1+1,"%[^\n]",e) )
        e[strlen(e)-n2]=0,a,b,c,d,e;
                strrev(f), strrev(g),strrev(h), strrev(i), strrev(j), strrev(k),
                strrev(l),strrev(m), strrev(n), strrev(o), strrev(p), strrev(q);
                strrev(r), strrev(s), strrev(tt), strrev(u), strrev(v), strrev(w),
                strrev(x), strrev(y), strrev(z), strrev(aa), strrev(ab), strrev(ac),
                strrev(ad), strrev(ae), strrev(af), strrev(ag), strrev(ah), strrev(ai),
                strrev(aj), strrev(ak),strrev(al), strrev(am), strrev(an), strrev(ao),
                strrev(ap), strrev(aq), strrev(ar), strrev(as), strrev(at), strrev(au),
                strrev(av), strrev(aw), strrev(ax), strrev(ay), strrev(az), strrev(ba);
                strrev(bb), strrev(bc), strrev(bd), strrev(be), strrev(bf), strrev(bg);
                strrev(bh), strrev(bi);
        // print first 5 columns in the console
         printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n",a, b, c, d, e);
        // print all parsed columns in output.txt file
         fprintf(fpp,"%s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s; %s\n",a,b,c,d,e,f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m ,n, o,p,q,r,s,tt,u,v,w,x,y,z,aa,ab,ac,ad,ae,af,ag,ah,ai,aj,ak,al,am,an,ao,ap,aq,ar,as,at,au,av,aw,ax,ay,az,ba,bb,bc,bd,be,bf,bg,bh,bi);
       
    }
     
    fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be parsing fields based on their start and end column.  Provided no fields extend beyond their column limits, that should work.

Comment: Separator seems to be *three* spaces – you might possibly count number of subsequent spaces, if less than three no separator, if more than three there must be an empty column (would actually mean more than six...). This won't work for two subsequent columns, though...

Comment: Data apparently is aligned – you might go over the file in two iterations, first determine the starting positions for all columns, again profiting from the multiple spaces: Wherever there are (at least) three spaces next non-space determines the beginning of a column. In second iteration you parse each entry within a line starting at the positions determined before until meeting multiple spaces again, denoting the end of current entry.

Comment: Are you in control of the file format? If so, then you might add a header line as very first line. You'd then only need one iteration, parse first line to determine starting positions for each column and then parse the following lines using this information. This approach is robust, too, against two subsequent columns being completely empty, too (you could determine that in above approach, too: If there's no data for a column at all then you should find e.g. 9 spaces in each line at the same position; would mean two entirely empty columns...).

Comment: The columns of all rows appear to be aligned up to character number 393, but afterwards, they are no longer aligned; some are displaced by one character. Does you actual input also have this displacement? If the length of all columns (including spaces) is always the same and clearly defined, then parsing the data and identifying empty columns should not be a problem. However, if there is no strict rule to the length of a column, then it may be impossible to distinguish an empty field from padding between two columns.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: The first 30 columns of all rows appear perfectly aligned. However, from the 31st column on, the columns of the first two rows are no longer aligned to the columns of the remaining rows. If your actual input data has inconsistent column lenghts, then parsing the data could be a lot harder, as the input could be ambiguous.

Comment: `"The separator is a space character"` - No, the separators are a varying sequence of whitespace. If your separate was actually a single `' '` character, you could simply consider two-spaces in sequence to be an empty-field -- that most certainly will not work for your data that you `fputs()` into the file.

Comment: @Aconcagua: Yes I have a header line as very first line. I think this is a similar approach like the answer from Andreas Wenzel. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: On a more high-level design perspective, perhaps [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) would be a better format for your file?

Comment: @Neil: Sure it is better having comma-separated values. After parsing the data i will now save it like that.

Comment: Side note: In order to create a temporary file for writing and reading from it later again, you can simply use the standard library function [tmpfile](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpfile), which will create a file for both writing and reading (i.e. it will create a file in "update mode"). There is no need to close and reopen the file. However, it is necessary to call `fseek` or `rewind` or a similar function when you change from writing to reading, and vice versa. See the documentation for [fopen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) for further information.

Comment: Don't use `sscanf` for complex parsing. Create your loop/logic and do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues mentioned in your question are easily solved, if all columns have a fixed length (including padding). This appears to be the case for all columns, except for the 30<sup>th</sup>/31<sup>st</sup> column. Since you have stated that this inconsistency in the input is not intended, I will restrict my answer to the first 10 columns, as those are the columns that you are asking about in your question.

It appears that your input data has the following format:

Every row in the file

- starts with `column #1` which consists of `5` characters, followed by `3` spaces,
- followed by `column #2` which consists of `10` characters, followed by `3` spaces
- followed by `column #3` which consists of `8` characters, followed by `3` spaces
- followed by `column #4` which consists of `8` characters (which may also be spaces), followed by `3` spaces,
- followed by `column #5` which consists of `25` characters (which may also be spaces), followed by `13` spaces,
- followed by `column #6` which consists of `5` characers (which may also be spaces), followed by `9` spaces
- followed by `column #7` which consists of `5` characters (which may also be spaces), followed by `4` spaces,
- followed by `column #8` which consists of `2` characters, followed by `17` spaces,
- followed by `column #9` which consists of `5` characters (which may also be spaces), followed by `6` spaces,
- followed by `column #10`, which consists of `1` character, followed by `7` spaces,
- followed by further input that I will disregard for the reason stated above.

If you have more input data than you posted, then the rules described above may not be correct. It is possible that in the input data that you are not showing us, one field may be larger, so that there is less padding of spaces between the two columns. However, for demonstration purposes, I will assume that the rules for the input data are as described above. You may have to adjust these rules for your actual input data.

If you tell the program the length of the data in every column and the number of spaces after the column that are used for padding, then the program will be able to determine which characters belong to which column. That way, the program will be able to find and read empty columns that only consist of spaces.

I do not recommend using the `%s` conversion format specifier with `sscanf`, as that will ignore any leading space characters. You are not allowed to ignore these space characters, because examining the number of space characters is required to find empty fields. Instead, I recommend handling the characters individually.

Here is an example using the first 10 columns of your input data:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_COLUMNS 10
#define MAX_COLUMN_LENGTH 200

//NOTE: This number should not be set too high, otherwise a
//stack overflow may occur. On non-embedded platforms, a
//size of up to 500,000 should generally be safe.
#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 8000

int main( void )
{
    //local variable declarations
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH+1];

    //define the column lengths (data length and padding length)
    const struct column_length
    {
        int data;
        int padding;

    } column_lengths[NUM_COLUMNS] =
    {
        {  5,  3 },
        { 10,  3 },
        {  8,  3 },
        {  8,  3 },
        { 25, 13 },
        {  5,  9 },
        {  5,  4 },
        {  2, 17 },
        {  5,  6 },
        {  1,  0 }
    };

    //open temporary file
    fp = tmpfile();
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening temporary file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //write data to temporary file
    fputs(
       "10000   07/01/1986   68391610   68391610   OPTIMUM MANUFACTURING INC             OMFGA          7952    10                 10396      3\n"
       "12781   30/11/1970   84857L10   50558810   LACLEDE GAS CO                        LG            21080    11                     0      1\n"
       "13901   27/05/1955   02209S10              PHILIP MORRIS & CO LTD                              21398    11                     0      1\n"
       "13901   31/05/1955   02209S10              PHILIP MORRIS & CO LTD                              21398    11                     0      1\n"
       "13901   01/06/1955   02209S10              PHILIP MORRIS INC                                   21398    11                     0      1\n"
       "13901   02/06/1955   02209S10              PHILIP MORRIS INC                                   21398    11                     0      1\n"
       "13901   03/06/1955   02209S10              PHILIP MORRIS INC                                   21398    11                     0      1\n",
       fp
    );

    //seek back to the beginning of the temporary file
    rewind( fp );

    //process one row per loop iteration
    for ( int row = 0; fgets(line,sizeof line,fp) != NULL; row++ )
    {
        //2D array for reading in all fields of a row
        char fields[NUM_COLUMNS][MAX_COLUMN_LENGTH+1];

        //this pointer will always point to the next
        //character of the line to process
        const char *p = line;

        printf( "Processing row #%d:\n", row );

        //verify that an entire line was read
        if ( strchr(line,'\n') == NULL && !feof(fp) )
        {
            fprintf(
                stderr,
                "Error processing row #%d:\n"
                "Buffer was too small to read the entire line.\n"
                "The macro constant MAX_COLUMN_LENGTH may have to be increased.\n",
                row
            );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //process one column per loop iteration
        for ( int col = 0; col < NUM_COLUMNS; col++ )
        {
            //verify that buffer size is large enough
            if ( column_lengths[col].data >= (int)sizeof fields[0] )
            {
                fprintf(
                    stderr,
                    "Error processing column #%d on row #%d: Buffer is too small!\n"
                    "The macro constant MAX_COLUMN_LENGTH must be increased.\n",
                    col, row
                );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            //extract data of the field
            for ( int i = 0; i < column_lengths[col].data; i++ )
            {
                if ( *p == '\0' || *p == '\n' )
                {
                    fprintf(
                        stderr,
                        "Error processing column #%d on row #%d:\n"
                        "Unexpected end of input encountered while reading the data area of a field!\n",
                        col, row
                    );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                fields[col][i] = *p;

                p++;
            }

            //add terminating null character
            fields[col][column_lengths[col].data] = '\0';

            //print the extracted field
            printf( "  Field #%d: \"%s\"\n", col, fields[col] );

            //skip padding and verify that it consists only of spaces
            for ( int i = 0; i < column_lengths[col].padding; i++ )
            {
                if ( *p != ' ' )
                {
                    if ( *p == '\0' || *p == '\n' )
                    {
                        fprintf(
                            stderr,
                            "Error processing column #%d on row #%d:\n"
                            "Unexpected end of input encountered while skipping the padding area of a field!\n",
                            col, row
                        );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fprintf(
                            stderr,
                            "Error processing column #%d on row #%d:\n"
                            "Non-space padding character encountered!\n",
                            col, row
                        );
                    }

                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                p++;
            }
        }

        printf( "\n" );
    }

    fclose( fp );
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Processing row #0:
  Field #0: "10000"
  Field #1: "07/01/1986"
  Field #2: "68391610"
  Field #3: "68391610"
  Field #4: "OPTIMUM MANUFACTURING INC"
  Field #5: "OMFGA"
  Field #6: " 7952"
  Field #7: "10"
  Field #8: "10396"
  Field #9: "3"

Processing row #1:
  Field #0: "12781"
  Field #1: "30/11/1970"
  Field #2: "84857L10"
  Field #3: "50558810"
  Field #4: "LACLEDE GAS CO           "
  Field #5: "LG   "
  Field #6: "21080"
  Field #7: "11"
  Field #8: "    0"
  Field #9: "1"

Processing row #2:
  Field #0: "13901"
  Field #1: "27/05/1955"
  Field #2: "02209S10"
  Field #3: "        "
  Field #4: "PHILIP MORRIS & CO LTD   "
  Field #5: "     "
  Field #6: "21398"
  Field #7: "11"
  Field #8: "    0"
  Field #9: "1"

Processing row #3:
  Field #0: "13901"
  Field #1: "31/05/1955"
  Field #2: "02209S10"
  Field #3: "        "
  Field #4: "PHILIP MORRIS & CO LTD   "
  Field #5: "     "
  Field #6: "21398"
  Field #7: "11"
  Field #8: "    0"
  Field #9: "1"

Processing row #4:
  Field #0: "13901"
  Field #1: "01/06/1955"
  Field #2: "02209S10"
  Field #3: "        "
  Field #4: "PHILIP MORRIS INC        "
  Field #5: "     "
  Field #6: "21398"
  Field #7: "11"
  Field #8: "    0"
  Field #9: "1"

Processing row #5:
  Field #0: "13901"
  Field #1: "02/06/1955"
  Field #2: "02209S10"
  Field #3: "        "
  Field #4: "PHILIP MORRIS INC        "
  Field #5: "     "
  Field #6: "21398"
  Field #7: "11"
  Field #8: "    0"
  Field #9: "1"

Processing row #6:
  Field #0: "13901"
  Field #1: "03/06/1955"
  Field #2: "02209S10"
  Field #3: "        "
  Field #4: "PHILIP MORRIS INC        "
  Field #5: "     "
  Field #6: "21398"
  Field #7: "11"
  Field #8: "    0"
  Field #9: "1"
```

As you can see, the empty fields were correctly read.

If desired, these fields can be processed further afterwards, for example by removing all leading and trailing space characters and converting numbers to `int` values using the function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: Sorry for my late response. The displacement is an error. The columns including spaces have always the same length.
Thank you for your help. I need some time to check your answer. I am just learning programming and your answer helps me a lot!

Comment: @JasminNiederbacher: I am pleased that I was able to help. Meanwhile, I have made some minor changes to my posted program. For example, I have added newline characters to the input, because that is also the input you will get when using the function `fgets` in your code. Also, I have improved the error handling of the program (the error messages are now more meaningful), and have also fixed a bug in the previous error handling.

Comment: @JasminNiederbacher: If you wish, I can rewrite my program so that it writes the input to a file and then reads it with `fgets`, as your code is doing, instead of reading from an array in memory, which my code is doing.

Comment: I think I can do that also on my own. But if you feel like it to change, I do not say no. I think your solution is helpful also to other people. Because with your approach it is possible to parse nearly every .txt file.

Comment: @JasminNiederbacher: I have now changed my program to read the input data from a temporary file, as your code does. However, I do not use a custom filename and I do not open the same file twice, once for writing and once for reading. Instead, I simply use the standard library function [`tmpfile`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/tmpfile) which opens the file in read/write ("update") mode.

Comment: Ok thanks. I did not knew the standard library function `tmpfile`, thanks for the hint.